# mysql Query to get list of months name from two dates

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a list of months name between two dates. What is the best way to do via mysql query.

```
Select start_date, end_date from table where id=123
```

above query  result -  start date: '2016-01-15' end date: '2017-04-28'

The final result should be:

```
Jan-16
Feb-16
Mar-16
......
......
......
Feb-17
Mar-17
Apr-17
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you provide sample input?

Comment: I am getting start and end dates value by querying 'Select start_date, end_date from table where id = 123' but i don't know how to transform to get above results.

Comment: First of all, edit your question and add those informations, don't put them in comments. Then, can you share some sample data from the table you're querying? Its structure would be nice too

Comment: I have amended my initial request. Thank for the information Stefano!

Answer (score 0):

dont have a time need to go now just Search for Date_Format to this `"date(thisday)"`

```
select CONCAT_WS('-',monthname(date(thisday)),substr(thisday from 9 FOR 2)) from

(SELECT ADDDATE('2017-01-01', INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS thisday
        FROM (
        SELECT a.a
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
        ) a
        JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
        WHERE 
        @i < DATEDIFF('2017-01-31', '2017-01-01')) as a
```

Some result:

```
January-18
January-19
January-20
January-21
January-22
January-23
January-24
January-25
January-26
January-27
January-28
January-29
```